# Calcular distância entre dois índices de uma matriz?

Tags: c#, c, matriz

Quero entrar com dois índices da matriz, e subtrair esse valor.

Por exemplo quero entrar com índice **`[0, 1]`** e **`[2, 10]`**. E ai quero subtrair o valor, pra calcular a distância que estou entre esses pontos.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
   {
     matriz = matriz1[i, j] - matriz2[i, j];
   }
}
```

Fiz dessa forma, porém me retorna zero. Retorna zero porque ele assume o valor para os índices, e não a posição deles.

Tem como eu fazer isso?

Eu preciso de chegar no valor que representa a quantos indíces quando eu estiver no **`[0, 1]`** estarei do **`[2, 10]`**

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o que já fez e dizer onde está com dificuldade.

Comment: A dúvida é em C# ou C?

Comment: Pesquise por "distância manhattan"

Comment: Acho que `i = 0; i < 1;i++` não vai pra lugar nenhum. Acho.

Answer (score 1):

Se o código foi escrito corretamente,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

vai cair no primeiro loop.

Vai assumir `i = 0`na primeira iteração, cair na condição `i<1` e retornar `false` . Nem entra na segunda iteração.

Fora isso. Se você quer calcular a distância entre dois pontos em uma matriz de 2x2, a resposta é que você precisa de uma fórmula matemática.

1) Calcule o quadrado da distância entre dois pontos de uma das ordenada.

2) Calcule o quadrado da distância entre dois pontos da outra ordenada.

3) Calcule a raiz quadrada da soma de 1) e 2).